Text not wrapping in older versions of Safari using Tailwind
Been trying to figure out this for a while - the text-wrap property does not seem to work properly in versions 16.5 and under on Safari (works fine on 17.4+) but all other browsers seem to work great. Anyone have any ideas? I am out of them.  HTML with Tailwind below (this is using Phoenix Liveview & Elixir). Thanks.
  <div style={@card_background} class={"#{@class} w-40 h-40 md:w-60 md:h-60 lg:w-80 lg:h-80 rounded-2xl grid grid-cols-1 text-white bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-[center_center]"}>
      <div :if={@verticals !== []} class="mt-0.5 sm:ml-0.5 flex h-fit flex-col xl:flex-row">
        <%= for vertical <- @verticals do %>
          <span class="mr-1 mb-[5px] flex items-center justify-center bg-white rounded-full text-navy text-xs md:text-sm font-medium w-fit px-0.4">
            <%= vertical.title %>
          </span>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrap self-end flex flex-col justify-end outline-none cursor-pointer ignore-sanity-formatting">
        <div class="sm:line-clamp-3 text-sm md:text-xl rounded-b-2xl font-medium font-graphik bg-gray-darkerBlue backdrop-blur-xl bg-opacity-40 px-0.5 md:px-1.5 pt-0.25 lg:pt-0.75 md:min-h-[7rem] min-h-[4rem] hover:brightness-125">
          <div class="flare-text mt-0.25 sm:mt-0 h-2.75 sm:h-4 md:leading-6 line-clamp-3 md:line-clamp-none">
            <%= @title %> text aint wrapping text aint wrapping
          </div>
          <div :if={@progress}>
            <div class="project-progress sm:mt-1 w-full flex items-center gap-x-1 relative">
              <div class="w-full h-0.5 grow rounded-full bg-white/20 backdrop-blur-sm overflow-hidden mx-0.5 md:mx-0">
                <div class="project-progress-bar-inner absolute left-0 h-0.5 w-0 rounded-r-full transition-[width] bg-green-onPace" style={"width: #{@progress}%"}></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


